# Chess: The Gathering tutorial?

Tags: chess-the-gathering

[Chess: The Gathering](http://misfitsattic.blogspot.ca/2012/11/chess-gathering-paper-prototype.html) has little to no documentation in its current state, and I have absolutely no idea what's going on.  Is there a manual or tutorial for it somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The developers have now posted a hastily made tutorial for CTG to Youtube.